# Interprocess message-queues: /dev/shm vs /dev/mqueue

Tags: linux

We have some C++ code in development that uses message-queues from the Boost Interprocess library, they work well.  Just for fun and learning, I'm trying to re-implement one of the executables in Rust, using message-queues from the "ipc" crate.
No go! messages from the C++ app don't get through to the Rust app.  After some head-scratching, it turns out that the Boost library creates its queues in **`/dev/shm`**, whereas Rust ipc creates them in **`/dev/mqueue`**!

So opinions please - which is the "right" device-node for message-queues to be created under?  Or should an IPC library allow the root device-node to be specified?

Comment: You can implement message queue by either mechanism. Depends on your needs. This is too board. Also what do you mean by "root device-node"?

Comment: Think I understand it now - Rust IPC provides a wrapper around Linux's Posix message-queue functions, whereas Boost provides a completely separate, self-contained and cross-platform implementation of message-queues.  The two types of message-queue are entirely separate and different, and will never be inter-compatible.

Comment: IPC is always platform dependent, so boost IPC abstraction rely on the OS provided shared memory mechanism

Answer (score 3):

Basically, shared mem and message Queues are different types of ipc, and work differently. Which one you Need, depends on your application.

With shared mem, you would create a Memory Region, which is mapped into the address space of two processes via:

```
handle = shm_open(Name /* '/dev/shm100' or similar*/, FLAGS);
/* now the memory can be mapped into address space */
address = mmap(0, SIZE, PROT, MAP_SHARED, &handle, 0);
```

You still need to synchronise the Access to the Memory via semaphores or similar.

Message Queues, on the other Hand, can be written and read from similar to regular files. **You Need to consider the Maximum size and Maximum message Count**, which can be configured via sysctrl:

```
fs.mqueue.msgsize_max = 9000
fs.mqueue.queues_max = 1024
```

The calls to send and receive would be:

```
mqd_t queue = mq_open(MQ_NAME, O_RDWR);
msg_size = mq_timedreceive(queue , request, SIZE, 0, (const struct timespec*) &my_timeout);
/* or */
int ret = mq_send(queue, (const char*) req, SIZE, 1);
mq_close(queue);
```